# SwiftUI Change Icon of List collapsible section

Tags: ios, swiftui

What's the best way to style and change the List Section arrow Icon?
And here's there a way to make the section Collapse as the Default State?

Here's how I'm creating my List:

```
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            List {
                ForEach(Array(self.dict!.keys.sorted()), id: \.self) { key in
                    if let tasks = self.dict![key] {
                        Section(header: Header(title: key, SubtitleText: Text(""), showTag: true, tagValue: tasks.count)
                                    .background(Color.white)
                                    .listRowInsets(inset)
                        ) {
                            ForEach(Array(tasks.enumerated()), id:\.1.title) { (index, task) in
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 40) {
                                    PillForRow(index: index, task: task)
                                        .padding(.bottom, 40)
                                }.onTapGesture {
                                    self.selectedTask = task
                                }
                            }
                        }.textCase(nil)
                    }
                }
                if let completedTasks = tasks.filter {$0.state == .Completed} {
                    Section(header: Header(title: "Completed", SubtitleText: Text(""), showTag: true, tagValue: tasks.count)
                                .background(Color.white)
                                .listRowInsets(inset)
                    ) {
                        ForEach(Array(completedTasks.enumerated()), id:\.1.title) { (index, task) in
                            PillForRow(index: index, task: task)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            
        }
```

[image: Section Image]